# NHibernate HQL - select count(*) with having - can't get it to work

Tags: nhibernate, hql, aggregate, having-clause

Trying to run the following HQL with NHibernate:

```
select count(distinct t) as TweetCount
from Tweet t
    join t.Tweeter u
    left join t.Votes v
    left join t.Tags tag
where t.App = :app
having count(distinct v) > 0
```

But for some reason the having clause is being ignored and it's counting all tweets when only 2 tweets have a vote. I basically want to count the number of Tweets that have at least one Vote.

Here is my database[image: My Twitter database]

I tried adding a group by to my query like so:

```
select count(distinct t) as TweetCount
from Tweet t
    join t.Tweeter u
    left join t.Votes v
    left join t.Tags tag
where t.App = :app
group by t
having count(distinct v) > 0
```

...but it ended up returning a collection containing 2 integers each set to '1' instead of a unique result.

Comment: What do you think the SQL should look like? Is it even possible without subqueries? (my gut tells me it's not)

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon: You're right, I tried to write the T-SQL equivalent and it didn't work either, I had to write a sub-query. Will post my answer later today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will fit thwe bill

```
select count(distinct t.Id) as TweetCount
from Tweet t
    inner join t.Votes v
where t.App = :app
```

since we are inner joining the Votes table, any Tweet that has no votes will not be counted against the result set.

An other way using pure HQL syntax would be

```
select count(distinct t.Id) as TweetCount
from Tweet t
where t.App = :app and size(t.Votes) > 0
```

which will create an sql statement depending on your dialect, the size() function is hql-specific for collections, see 13.8 from the NHibernate reference